# State evolution for Dot product of quantum states (Llyod et al. 2013)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

I was reading the paper by [Lloyd et al.](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.0411v2.pdf) which is concerned with quantum machine learning algorithms. In the algorithm they use the evolution of the following kind (i use a reduced formula, which is taken from [this](http://peterwittek.com/book.html) book):
 $$\text{exp}\left\lbrace-i \left(||x_i|| \left|0\right> \left<0\right| + ||x_j|| \left|1\right> \left<1\right| \right ) \otimes \sigma_x \; t\right\rbrace $$ 
which is applied to this state
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\left|0\right>  - \left|1\right>  \right ) \otimes \left|0\right>$$
The result is given by:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left[\text{cos}(||x_i||t) \left|0\right>  - \text{cos}(||x_j||t)\left|1\right>  \right] \otimes \left|0\right>
-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \left[\text{sin}(||x_i||t) \left|0\right>  - \text{sin}(||x_j||t)\left|1\right>  \right] \otimes \left|1\right>
$$
I was trying to calculate this on my own but I wasn't successful. My trials were to separate the spaces and apply the left side (in the exponent) before the tensor-product to the left side and the right to the right side, which obviously fails to get the four states $\left|00\right> \ldots \left|11\right>$.
I also tried to apply all one after another but as well ended up in a wrong result.Could somebody point out how to apply this operator to this state to me?

Comment: Where does $t$ come from? What's the range of $x_{i,j}$? Finally your unitary is just $4$-dimensional; just compute it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the $\sigma_x$ exponential is not so hard.

Let's start by expanding the evolution:
$$
\exp\left[ -i \left( \|x_i\||0\rangle\langle 0| + \|x_j\||1\rangle\langle 1| \right)\otimes \sigma_x \;t\right] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-it)^n}{n!}\left[\left( \|x_i\||0\rangle\langle 0| + \|x_j\||1\rangle\langle 1| \right)\otimes \sigma_x\right]^n} =\\
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-it)^n}{n!}\left( \|x_i\||0\rangle\langle 0| + \|x_j\||1\rangle\langle 1| \right)^n\otimes \sigma_x^n}
$$
For the operator terms under the sum we have 
$$
\left( \|x_i\||0\rangle\langle 0| + \|x_j\||1\rangle\langle 1| \right)^n =  \|x_i\|^n|0\rangle\langle 0| + \|x_j\|^n|1\rangle\langle 1| 
$$
and also 
$$
\sigma_x^n = \left\{ \begin{array}{c} \sigma_x, \;\;\text{for}\;\; n = 2k+1\;, \;\;k = 0,1,2.. \\ I,  \;\;\text{for}\;\; n = 2k\;, \;\;k = 0,1,2,. ..  \end{array}\right.
$$
This yields
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-it)^n}{n!}\left( \|x_i\||0\rangle\langle 0| + \|x_j\||1\rangle\langle 1| \right)^n\otimes \sigma_x^n} = \\
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-it)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\left( \|x_i\|^{2k+1}|0\rangle\langle 0| + \|x_j\|^{2k+1}|1\rangle\langle 1| \right) }\otimes \sigma_x + \\
+ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-it)^{2k}}{(2k)!}\left( \|x_i\|^{2k}|0\rangle\langle 0| + \|x_j\|^{2k}|1\rangle\langle 1| \right) }\otimes I 
$$
Collapsing the tractable sums gives 
$$
\exp\left[ -i \left( \|x_i\||0\rangle\langle 0| + \|x_j\||1\rangle\langle 1| \right)\otimes \sigma_x \;t\right] = \\
= -i\left( \sin(\|x_i\|t)|0\rangle\langle 0| + \sin(\|x_j\|t)|1\rangle\langle 1|\right)\otimes \sigma_x + \left( \cos(\|x_i\|t)|0\rangle\langle 0| + \cos(\|x_j\|t)|1\rangle\langle 1|\right)\otimes I
$$
and applying the above to the given state,
$$
\exp\left[ -i \left( \|x_i\||0\rangle\langle 0| + \|x_j\||1\rangle\langle 1| \right)\otimes \sigma_x \;t\right] (|0\rangle -|1\rangle)\otimes |0\rangle =\\
= -i\left( \sin(\|x_i\|t)|0\rangle - \sin(\|x_j\|t)|1\rangle\right)\otimes |1\rangle + \left( \cos(\|x_i\|t)|0\rangle - \cos(\|x_j\|t)|1\rangle\right)\otimes |0\rangle = \\
= \left( \cos(\|x_i\|t)|0\rangle - \cos(\|x_j\|t)|1\rangle\right)\otimes |0\rangle - i\left( \sin(\|x_i\|t)|0\rangle - \sin(\|x_j\|t)|1\rangle\right)\otimes |1\rangle
$$

Comment: Yes that's correct, I was just mentioning it so nobody would forget about it :) Thanks for the answer!